# How can fastText or Gensim train additional data from pre-trained data (.bin)?

Tags: gensim, bin, fasttext

I got a file regarding pre-trained data from this link: (.bin file)https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html

and I want to use this file on input layer of neural network(maybe its' forms vector)

I want pre-trained data learn more of training data. ( let' call training data as data.txt.)

and I have loaded pre-trained model using fasttext 
and genism library however I don't know how to train them more.

```
import fasttext
model = fasttext.load_model('model.bin')
#whatever using data.txt
```

or

```
from gensim.models import FastText
model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('model.bin')
#whatever using data.txt
```

please advice.

Comment: What makes you think the `gensim` approach isn't working for you?

Comment: I changed my question. sorry